# Dynamic property binding inside ngFor

Tags: angular, semantic-ui

i am trying to bind a toggle for displaying content using [suiCollapse].
the problem is the way i am binding them now they all have the same name and thus they all open when i click on the icon.

I tried using the index as a modifier but it didn't work. 
example: 

`(click) = "collapse+{{index}} = !collapse+{{index}}"`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] let i=index" class="ui segment">
 <div class="ui grid middle aligned">
   <div (click)="collapse = !collapse" class="one wide column center aligned">
    <i class="blue large toggle down icon"></i>
  </div>

 <div [suiCollapse]="!collapse" class="ui grid center aligned">
  <div class="column">
    <p>Content of the panel.</p>
    <p>Content of the panel.</p>
    <p>Content of the panel.</p>
    <p>Content of the panel.</p>
    <p>Content of the panel.</p>  
  </div>
</div>
```

any help is appreciated. I am trying to do this bus only using the template but if its not possible i can put some logic inside the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*ngFor="let item of[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] let i=index"
```

Why would you use the index when your array is made of indexes ?

And you don't seem to comprehend the Angular syntax : writing an input/output such as `(click)` or `[myVar]` will **evaluate the content of this attribute as JS**.

So if you write

```
(click) = "collapse+{{index}} = !collapse+{{index}}"
```

Angular will try to do this :

```
collapse+{{index}} = !collapse+{{index}}
```

And that isn't Javascript.

If you want it to work, here it is :

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" class="ui segment">
 <div class="ui grid middle aligned">
   <div (click)="collapse[item] = !collapse[item]" class="one wide column center aligned">
    <i class="blue large toggle down icon"></i>
  </div>

 <div [suiCollapse]="!collapse[item]" class="ui grid center aligned">
  <div class="column">
    <p>Content of the panel.</p>
    <p>Content of the panel.</p>
    <p>Content of the panel.</p>
    <p>Content of the panel.</p>
    <p>Content of the panel.</p>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Remember to declare your variable `collapse` as an array/object of booleans !

Comment: The reason for the array of indexes was just for testing purposes. later it will be actual items in the array. I was trying to use index because i am not sure if i want to use something like an id of the incomming item wich might be really long if i can use the index.  Is it possible to use the index for this or am i stuck using a value of the array?

Comment: No, you can use the index, I just thought you really wanted to use an array of numbers like this :D add an index to your *ngFor, and replace every `[item]` with `[index]`

Comment: it wont work that way. it assumes that i am trying to get to something within collapse. so it thinks its an array and i get the error of cannot read property of undefined. i guess i have to add an index to the item itself?

Comment: Did you change your variable collapse to be an array of booleans ?

Comment: oh sorry , yea your version works but i ended up looping over a component so that the functionality was divided between each looped component. each scope was therefore related to only one item of the list.  Ill mark your answer as right since it helped me learn more.